# Полторы ставки

Tags: морфология

Работники, имеющие нагрузку не более полутора (полторы) ставки (ставок).

Как правильно в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... полутора ставок". Никаких сомнений.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, правильно *не более полутора ставок*. Если грызут сомнения, можно написать *не более, чем полторы ставки.*

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Числительное *полтора(ы)* имеет только две формы: в именительном и винительном падежах *полтора(ы)* , в остальных падежах *полутора.* В данном случае падеж родительный, значит, *полутора ставок*